# Combinatorial formulas and interpretations

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial

I found that
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{s}(n-s+j)!\binom{s}{j}(s-j)! =s!  \sum_{j=0}^{s} \frac{(n-s+j)!}{j!} = \frac{(n+1)!}{n+1-s}$$
I proved this formula with induction, but I was wondering if there is a (combinatorial?) interpretation that can explain it.

Moreover, I wanted to simplify in a similar way also the following:

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{s}(n-s+j)!\binom{s}{j}3^{s-j}(s-j)! = s! 3^s \sum_{j=0}^{s} \frac{(n-s+j)!}{j!3^j} = ?$$
is it possible?

Comment: If you divide your first identity through by $n!$ and reverse the order of summation, then it can be written $$\sum_{j=0}^s \binom{s}{j}\binom{n}{j}^{-1} = \frac{n+1}{n+1-s}$$ which is rather cute. (It also makes the $n=s$ case immediately obvious.) There are likely other such sums of ratios of binomial coefficients that have come up as questions, and these could have what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the notation $x^{\underline k}=x(x-1)\ldots(x-k+1)$ for the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials). First note that

$$\sum_{j=0}^s(n-s+j)!\binom{s}j(s-j)!=\sum_{j=0}^s(n-s+j)!s^{\underline{s-j}}=\sum_{j=0}^ss^{\underline j}(n-j)!\;.\tag{1}$$

Let $A=\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$; then $s^{\underline j}(n-j)!$ is the number of permutations $a_0a_1\ldots a_n$ of $A$ such that $a_j=s$, and $a_i<s$ for $0\le i<j$. Summing over $j$ to get $(1)$ yields the number of permutations of $A$ in which every element preceding $s$ is smaller than $s$.

Now let $\pi=a_0a_1\ldots a_n$ be an arbitrary permutation of $A$. Let $j$ be minimal such that $a_j\ge s$, let $a_k=s$, and let $\pi'$ be the permutation that results from interchanging $a_j$ and $a_k$. Then $\pi'$ is one of the permutations counted by $(1)$, and the map $\pi\mapsto\pi'$ is $(n+1-s)$-to-$1$, so

$$\sum_{j=0}^s(n-s+j)!\binom{s}j(s-j)!=\sum_{j=0}^ss^{\underline j}(n-j)!=\frac{(n+1)!}{n+1-s}\;.$$

Similarly, we can rewrite

$$\sum_{j=0}^{s}(n-s+j)!\binom{s}{j}3^{s-j}(s-j)! = \sum_{j=0}^s3^js^{\underline j}(n-j)!\;.\tag{2}$$

If we think of the set $A$ above as a set of $n+1$ numbered white balls, $(2)$ is the number of ways of choosing a permutation of the type counted in $(1)$ and then painting each of the balls preceding ball $s$ independently with one of the three colors red, blue, and green. Unfortunately, I don’t see any nice way to count the outcomes in one go to simplify $(2)$.

Answer (score 12):

Here's another non-induction and non-combinatorial proof.

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{s}(n-s+j)!\binom{s}{j}(s-j)! &=s!  \sum_{j=0}^{s} \frac{(n-s+j)!}{j!} \cdot \color{lightgrey}{\frac{(n-s)!}{(n-s)!}}\\
&=s!(n-s)!\sum_{j=0}^s\binom {n-s+j}{n-s}\\
&=s!(n-s)!\binom {n+1}{n-s+1}
&&\tiny\text{using }\sum_{r=a}^b\binom {m+r}{m+a}=\binom {m+b+1}{m+a+1}\\
&=s! (n-s)!\frac {(n+1)!}{(n-s+1)!s!}\\
&=(n-s)!\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-s+1)!}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)!}{n-s+1}\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{s}(n-s+j)!\binom{s}{j}(s-j)! &=
n!\sum_{j=0}^s\frac{\binom sj}{\frac{n!}{(n-s+j)!(s-j)!}}\\
&=n!\sum_{j=0}^s\frac{\binom s{s-j}}{\binom n{s-j}}\\
&=\frac{n!}{\binom ns}\sum_{j=0}^s\frac{\binom ns\binom s{s-j}}{\binom n{s-j}}\\
&=\frac{n!}{\frac{n!}{s!(n-s)!}}\sum_{j=0}^s\frac{\binom n{s-j}\binom {n-s+j}{j}}{\binom n{s-j}}\\
&=s!(n-s)!\sum_{j=0}^s\binom {n-s+j}{n-s}\\
&=s!(n-s)!\binom{n+1}{n-s+1}\\
&=s!(n-s)! \frac{(n+1)!}{(n-s+1)!s!}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)!}{n-s+1}\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio - Thanks! Coming from you that means a lot :)

Answer (score 8):

I am getting:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{j=0}^{s}\binom{s}{j}(n-s+j)!(s-j)!&=&\iint_{(0,+\infty)^2}\sum_{j=0}^{s}\binom{s}{j}x^{s-j} y^{n-s+j} e^{-(x+y)}\,dx\,dy\\&=&\iint_{(0,+\infty)^2} x^s y^n e^{-(x+y)}\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\right)^s\,dx\,dy\\&=&\iint_{(0,+\infty)^2} y^{n-s} e^{-(x+y)}(x+y)^s\,dx\,dy\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{u}y^{n-s} e^{-u} u^s\,dy\,du\\&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{1} v^{n-s} e^{-u} u^{n+1}\,dv\,du\\&=&\color{red}{\frac{(n+1)!}{n-s+1}}\end{eqnarray*}$$

but I do not know if that counts as a combinatorial proof :D

Anyway, we may easily throw in an additional $3^{s-j}$ factor:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{j=0}^{s}\binom{s}{j}3^{s-j}(n-s+j)!(s-j)!&=&\iint_{(0,+\infty)^2}\sum_{j=0}^{s}\binom{s}{j}(3x)^{s-j} y^{n-s+j} e^{-(x+y)}\,dx\,dy\\&=&\iint_{(0,+\infty)^2} y^{n-s} e^{-(x+y)}\left(3x+y\right)^s\,dx\,dy\\&=&\frac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{1}u^{n+1} v^{n-s}\exp\left(-\frac{u}{3}-uv\right)\,dv\,du\end{eqnarray*}$$

but that does not simplify nicely as before, since $\int_{0}^{1}v^{n-s}e^{-uv}\,dv$ depends on a exponential integral. From the last identity, with the help of a CAS I got:

> $$ \sum_{j=0}^{s}\binom{s}{j}3^{s-j}(n-s+j)!(s-j)!\\ = \color{red}{3^{s+1}n!(s-n)!} -\frac{(n+1)!}{s+1}\color{blue}{\,\phantom{}_2 F_1\left(n+2,s+1;s+2;-\frac{1}{3}\right)}. $$

At least, the $\color{blue}{\text{non-trivial part}}$ is given by a fast-convergent series.

Comment: Well, it's certainly not a proof by induction! (+1)

Comment: Nice double integral! (+1)